# c++ strange behavior ... same variable contains different values

Tags: html, c++, css

I am building a c++ program that deal with CSS and i was blocked in front of this not-understandable behavior.
So the thing is, i have a class HTMLObject which is inherited from CSS class like so:
CSS class declaration:

```
struct Border {
    string bottom;
    string bottom_color;
    string bottom_left_radius;
    string bottom_right_radius;
    string bottom_style;
    //... lot of other string 
};

struct Background {
    string color;
    string image;
    string position;
    string size_;
    string repeat;
    string origin;
    string clip;
    string attachment;
};

struct Margin {
    string top, right, bottom, left;
};

struct Padding {
    string top, right, bottom, left;
};

class CSS {
private:

public:
    string position, display, height, width;
    string top, right, bottom, left;
    string color;
    string min_width, min_height, max_width, max_height;
    string overflow, opacity, text_align, z_index;
    Margin margin;
    Padding padding;
    Background background;
    Border border; // declared above this code but its too long to be added here
    Font font; // declared above this code but its too long to be added here
};
```

CSS HTMLObject declaration:

```
class HTMLObject : public CSS
{
public:
    //..some members and methodes
    CSS css;
    string GetCSS()
    {
         // i m in std namespace...
         cout << "instance address: " << this << " " << 
                 this->css.background.image << this->css.color << " " << 
                 this->css.border.bottom << endl;
         //.
         //.
         //.
         //the rest of the code without forgetting to return a string
    }
};
```

Then, i have some other class that inherit from HTMLObject like so:
cClass1 declaration:

```
class cClass1 : public HTMLObject
    {
    private:


    public:
        cClass1() : HTMLObject("instantiated"){} // calling HTMLObject constructor ...
    };
typedef cClass1*        Class1;
```

and finally the main function:
main() implementation:

```
Class1 b = new cClass1();
b->css.color="red";
b->css.border.bottom="3px";
b->background.image="-webkit-linear-gradient(#ffffff 0%, #F6F6F6 30%, #F3F3F3 45%, #EDEDED 60%, #eeeeee 100%)";
cout << "Var address:" << b << " " << b->background.image << endl << endl;
cout << b->GetCSS() << endl;

cout << "GetCSS() finished.\n";
```

What i m getting in the output is not like what i was expecting...it's driving me crazy!!

Output:

```
Var address:0x55e3b0b83ae0 -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffffff 0%, #F6F6F6 30%, #F3F3F3 45%, #EDEDED 60%, #eeeeee 100%)


instance address: 0x55e3b0b83ae0 red 3px

GetCSS() finished.
```

(https://i.ibb.co/LCj8jpR/Untitled.png)

N.B: *I m using GCC (GNU Compiler) and i obtained this result on both Ubuntu and MacOSX*

Comment: `HTMLObject` inherits from `CSS` **and** contains a `CSS` member...

Comment: So `this->css.background.image` is other variable than `this->background.image`.

Comment: Thank you Jarod42, i didnt pay attention to this because i wasnt using inheritance in the beginning and also CSS was a struct.

Comment: @Jarod42.
by the way, its true that `this->css.background.image` is different than `this->background.image`, but do you have any idea why `this->css.color` was same as `this->color` and also `this->css.margin.bottom`?

Comment: There are different too. (but might have same value (with same initialization for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HTMLObject` inherits from `CSS` **and** contains a `CSS` member...

So you have 2 CSS data:

`this->css.background.image` is other variable than `this->background.image`.

You probably should get rid of inheritance

```
class HTMLObject 
{
public:
    CSS css;
    string GetCSS();
    // ...
};
```

And fix `main` (`background.image` -> `css.background.image`):

```
cClass1 b;
b.css.color="red";
b.css.border.bottom="3px";
b.css.background.image="-webkit-linear-gradient(#ffffff 0%, #F6F6F6 30%, #F3F3F3 45%, #EDEDED 60%, #eeeeee 100%)";
cout << "Var address:" << &b << " " << b.css.background.image << endl << endl;
cout << b.GetCSS() << endl;

cout << "GetCSS() finished.\n";
```